# Deeper levels in reducer getting overwritten

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an action that fetches some data from a database using multiple calls. I am trying to create the correct structure for my data in the reducer, but the deeper levels of the object just get overwritten.

React call:

```
_.forEach(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4'], (category) => {
    _.forEach(['day1', 'day2', 'day3'], (day) => {
        this.props.fetchSingleResult('2018', 'USA', day, category)
    })
})
```

My action:

```
export function fetchSingleResult(year, venue, day, category) {
// Get race result from a single category and day
const request = axios.get('/api/races/singleresult',
    {params: {
        year: year,
        venue: venue,
        day: day,
        category: category }
    });
return {
    type: FETCH_SINGLE_RESULT,
    payload: request,
    meta: {year: year, venue: venue, day: day, category: category}
};
}
```

My reducer:

```
case FETCH_SINGLE_RESULT:
        return {...state,
            [action.meta.year]: {...state[action.meta.year],
                [action.meta.venue]: {...state[action.meta.venue],
                    [action.meta.category]: {...state[action.meta.category],
                        [action.meta.day]: action.payload.data}}}};
```

The output of this is an object that comes from this only has the last day and category as keys i.e.

```
{2018: {'USA': {'cat4': {'day3' : data}}}}
```

instead of having all categories and days like:

```
{2018: 
    {'USA': 
        {'cat1': {'day1' : data, 'day2' : data, 'day3' : data}}, 
        {'cat2': {'day1' : data, 'day2' : data, 'day3' : data}}, 
        {'cat3': {'day1' : data, 'day2' : data, 'day3' : data}}, 
        {'cat4': {'day1' : data, 'day2' : data, 'day3' : data}}
     }
}
```

Any ideas?

There are a lot of years and a lot of venues.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @HassanImam Edited

Comment: @moto... i think your output would be in request object in payload not in FETCH_SINGLE_RESULT..

Comment: @MukulSharma I'm not sure what you mean? I am using ReduxPromise to handle the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using the spread operator is causing that result, try:

```
case FETCH_SINGLE_RESULT: 
  const {year, venue, category, day} = action.meta;
  return _.merge(state, {[year]: {[venue]: {[category]: {[day]: action.payload.data}}}});
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you give me a quick reason why using spread like that causes that?

Comment: Just for completeness, I had to use `{..._.merge(state, {[year]: {[venue]: {[category]: {[day]: action.payload.data}}}})}`

Comment: :+1: The correct syntax with the spread operators would look something like `{...state, [action.meta.year]: {...state[action.meta.year], [action.meta.venue]: {...state[action.meta.year][action.meta.venue], [action.meta.category]: {...state[action.meta.year][action.meta.venue][action.meta.category], [action.meta.day]: action.payload.data}}}}`

Comment: OMG, I feel so stupid now. Haha. Of course what I was doing didn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Look first of all this level of nesting is very difficult to maintain and respect immutability in react. You should change your data endpoint's response structure.

```
const getnewState = (state, action) => {
const initialStateValue = {...state }
const { year, venue, day, category } = action.meta
const data = action.payload
  if(initialStateValue[year]) {
    const currentYearValue = initialStateValue[year]
            if (currentYearValue[venue]) {
        const currentVenueValue = currentYearValue[venue]
        if(currentVenueValue[category]) {
          let currentCategoryValue = currentVenueValue[category]
            currentCategoryValue = {
          ...currentCategoryValue,
          [day]: data,
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I just handled one flow in this code above , you need to take care of other scenartios also like , if the key is iteself not there for all levels..
I went on to code the solution for this, but found it overly complex to code.

Comment: Thank you
How could I restructure my data to make it better?

Should I just do something like `{2018: {USA_cat1_day1: data, USA_cat1_day2}, etc}`

Comment: that will be much better